# vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage Memory Leak in Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, swift3, histogram

I am trying to get histogram calculation.  Everything works fine, except following method shows an immense memory leak when profiled in Instruments.

Every time following method is called, it uses 200-300 MB of memory and never releases:

```
       func histogramCalculation(_ imageRef: CGImage) -> (red: [UInt], green: [UInt], blue: [UInt]) {

            var inBuffer = vImage_Buffer() 

            vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage(
                &inBuffer,
                &format,
                nil,
                imageRef,
                UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))

            let alpha = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)
            let red = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)
            let green = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)
            let blue = [UInt](repeating: 0, count: 256)

            let alphaPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: alpha) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
            let redPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: red) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
            let greenPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: green) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?
            let bluePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>(mutating: blue) as UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?

            let rgba = [redPtr, greenPtr, bluePtr, alphaPtr]

            let histogram = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<vImagePixelCount>?>(mutating: rgba)
            let error : vImage_Error = vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888(&inBuffer, histogram, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))

            if (error == kvImageNoError) {
                return (red, green, blue)
            }
            return (red, green, blue)
}
```

What could be wrong here.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for `vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage` explain:

> You are responsible for returning the memory referenced by buf->data to the system using free() when you are done with it.

So I would expect something along these lines to clean up the memory:

```
inBuffer.data.deallocate(bytes: inBuffer.rowBytes * Int(inBuffer.height),
                         alignedTo: MemoryLayout<vImage_Buffer>.alignment)
```

As a side note, your use of `UnsafeMutablePointer` here is not safe. There's no promise, for instance, that `alpha` will exist by the time you use reference it. Swift is allowed to destroy `alpha` immediately after you create `alphaPtr` (because it's never referenced again). It is rare that you want to use `UnsafeMutablePointer.init`. Instead, you want to use `withUnsafe...` methods to establish guaranteed lifetimes. For example (untested, but compiles):

```
var alpha = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)
var red = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)
var green = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)
var blue = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)

let error = alpha.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { alphaPtr -> vImage_Error in
    return red.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { redPtr in
        return green.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { greenPtr in
            return blue.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { bluePtr in
                var rgba = [redPtr.baseAddress, greenPtr.baseAddress, bluePtr.baseAddress, alphaPtr.baseAddress]
                return rgba.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { buffer in
                    return vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888(&inBuffer, buffer.baseAddress!, UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GREAT answer! Works!

Comment: I believe free(inBuffer.data) would have also worked?

Comment: hahaha yeah… I forgot that `free` would be imported via `Darwin` (been spending so much time in raw Swift). Probably even better to call the thing they say to call…